# Show me a way to sort an eloquent collection by complex condition without raw SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to make a sorting system that will order posts by complex factors. For example, Reddit is using a complex condition for their Controversial sorting.

I have a model called `Post` that is attached to a MySQL table called `Posts`. I also have tables `upvotes` and `downvotes` that include `created_at` (a timestamp field) and `post_id` (an int unsigned field).

Let's define `l` as upvotes for past 7 days (`l = 1` for zero upvotes) and `d` as downvotes for past 7 days (`d = 1` for zero downvotes), `m` as a magnitude that is equal to `l + d` and `k` as a coefficient that is `d / l` if `l > d` and `l / d` otherwise. The score I want the posts to be sorted by from highest to lowest is calculated as `m^k` (m in power of k).

How to execute complex things like this one in a proper way?

I think that using `Post::orderByRaw(/* some SQL code here */)` will be messy and adding a custom field named **score** and doing `Post::sort('score')` will not be good with a lot of posts (e.g. >10k posts).

Comment: I think if you can form the query in SQL first, it may be more apparent how to do it with the builder.

Comment: Getting post's upvotes for last week: `SELECT GREATEST(COUNT(*),1) FROM upvotes WHERE 'created_at' >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK`
Same for getting downvotes, just with a different table name.

m is `SUM(retrieved_upvotes,retrieved_downvotes)` where retreived_upvotes and retrieved_downvotes are the queries above. 

k is `CASE WHEN retrieved_upvotes > retrieved_downvotes THEN retrieved_downvotes / retrieved_upvotes ELSE retrieved_upvotes / retrieved_downvotes END`

score is `POW(k,m)`. I know how to do individual queries for this but can't put them together.

Comment: I don't think there is a way here. One solution would be to put the raw sql logic into some function and give a nice name to it. You will still use Raw, but at least your code will be isolated somewhere.

Comment: So basically I must still use a lot of identic selects but just put separate statements in separate variables so it won't look messy?